# react native react-native-geocoding address will not render

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, google-geocoder

i am creating an app to display user add using react native

after getting user permission and latitude,longitude using expo i used react-native-geocoding to turn cords to address but address would not display

expo permission code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert,Platform,StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';

import AppStackNav from '../party/src/nav/appStackNav';


import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';

Geocoder.init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    addressComponent: null,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  } 

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    });
    this.setState({ location  });
      let lat = this.state.location.coords.latitude;
      let long = this.state.location.coords.longitude;

      Geocoder.from(lat,long).then(json => 
        {
        var addressComponent = json.results[0].formatted_address;
        this.setState({addressComponent})

          // Alert.alert(this.state.addressComponent)
      }) 
  }
```

then attempt to display the address while passing as a prop

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,FlatList} from 'react-native'

import styles from '../style/styles';

class SetConn extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>

                     <Text style={styles.addyComp}>{this.props.addressComponent}</Text> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default SetConn;
```

Comment: what does the render method return in App? One thought is that it doesn't pass down the prop correctly.

Comment: on the app or in app,js

Comment: We need to see the whole of the render method so we know everything related to the question

Comment: well as far as the SetCon Component that is all being render and this is the rest of the code for the app.js

Comment: this.setState({ location  });
      let lat = this.state.location.coords.latitude;
      let long = this.state.location.coords.longitude;

      Geocoder.from(lat,long).then(json => 
        {   var addressComponent = json.results[0].formatted_address;
        this.setState({addressComponent})
      })
  }
  render() {  console.log(" waiting. .");
    if   (this.state.errorMessage)   {
      console.log (this.state.errorMessage)
    } else if (this.state.location) {
      console.log(this.state.addressComponent)
    }
    return (
      <AppStackNav />
    );
  }
}

Comment: It looks like you need to pass this.state.addressComponent down as a prop. SetConn can't magically access it until you actually give it the prop. You can console log in SetConn to see if the value is undefined or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [react-native-geocoder api](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder#usage) works from `human readable address` -> `latitude longitude`.

Use [google reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) instead.

Comment: the question is about `react-native-geocoding` not about `react-native-geocoder`.

`react-native-geocoding` provides human readable address from lat and lng